# Karate GraphQL test - Does not have matching glue in Eclipse?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, graphql, bdd, karate

I am insanely new so forgive me first but I have spent tons of time already researching and playing here how to do some kind of API testing using Karate or Cucumber for our GraphQL tests.  I have experience with Cucumber using Ruby but that was REST API's and we are using GraphQL so I think it needs to be changed.  I have tried using Karate now in Eclipse and using the examples from here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/graphql.  I thought there needed to not be any step defs with Karate so I am unsure why when just copying/pasting the examples I am getting errors in Eclipse stating the steps do not have matching glue code.

My folder structure is very simple so maybe I am missing something, again, I'm SUPER new so just trying to get some help.  If only they chose to go with REST I'd be back with Cucumber.  If anyone has a suggestion or maybe a better route to test the GraphQL API's another way I'd be happy to take a suggestion for automating this.

[image: Error]

[image: Folder Structure]

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is solved if you use the right Cucumber plugin for Eclipse.

Just look at the information in this ticket and you should be up and running !: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/90

Comment: I tried both options in the ticket you suggested and it didn't help.  I tried these:  Eclipse --> Preferences --> Cucumber --> User Settings

In the text-field for "Add Root Package Name .." enter com.intuit.karate

In some cases, even this does not work. Then go to the "Run Configuration" for the feature you were attempting to run and use com.intuit.karate instead of classpath: for the 'Glue'.

Comment: @ptrthomas That actually did resolve the color coding/error about the glue.  I now have a ton of errors about having undefined steps so essentially the same issue when I run it but that did fix it.